Light fixture wiring - white wire is hot
I am installing a new light fixture that has three wires in the fixture. A white wire, black wire, and ground wire. There are also 3 wires coming from the house. The wires are also white, black, and ground wire. The white wire coming from the house is the hot wire. I know it typically goes black to black, white to white, and ground to ground. The directions from the install instructions also shows that.  However, since the white wire from house is hot do I connect it to the black wire from fixture? Here is a picture of the switch wiring and the wires in junction box.


You should look at how the switch is wired.

@DJ. on the switch there is a white to brass, black to brass and ground to green. This switch controls two light fixtures if that matters.

At the switch, is there only one white/black cable or two?  If one, then the ceiling wire connections are messed up, If two then the switch wires are messed up.

Smells of "Pre NEC2011 switch loop" but we need pictures of the relevant locations to sort out the "but not one done right" it reeks of. A hot white from power at fixture to switch is correct for those, but does not connect to the fixture at all, and should connect to hot black wherever it gets power from (typically at the fixture.) Then hot white goes to switch, and switched hot runs on black from the switch to the light, where a white neutral should be. So this wiring is wrong, somewhere.

@Ecnerwal the electrician just did this yesterday. Up at the light fixture box the two white wires are twisted together and the two black wires are twisted together.

If you turn the switch off is there a change (such as white wire no longer hot)? Are you measuring whether it's hot with a volt meter or with a non-contact tester? Would you include information about the connections at the second fixture?

Please show us the wiring at the switch. If using old wiring (did not run new cables) there might not be an up-to-date date switch loop, but this is not consistent with an old-style switch loop to code.

Picture of the switch showing how the wires are connected and if any wires in the box will help.  Black to black and white to white is good about 60 or 75 percent of the time.  You probably have the other 25%.

If power is on to the circuit and you turn the switch on, does the circuit breaker trip?

@Ecnerwal No, it doesn’t. With the current wiring shown in light fixture junction box (2 whites twisted together, 2 blacks twisted together and 2 grounds together) and the wires to the switch, the one light turns on when switch is on. I am just trying to install the second light fixture on the switch

So, what does the wiring at the "one" fixture look like?

The switch seems to be wired correctly for an old style switch loop, except the white should be marked with black or red colour.
You need to undo the wires in the ceiling and find which set of black/white is from the panel/power and which is from the switch.
The white from the switch should be connected to the black power wire and also marked black or red.
The black from the switch(switch hot) is connected to the black from the light.
The ceiling white(neutral) is connected to the white from the light.

Ok that seems to make sense to me. As for new code it appears that I will need a 12/3 wire into the switch box for neutral. Does every wire need to be switched to 12/3 or just the wire that comes into the switch box?

@DIYNoob just the cable from the light box to the switch box

@DIYNoob    Quite sure that switch would be grandfather in and do not need to change cable to 12/3.  The newer code for switches using /3 cables is for using/adding smart switches, since most of them require neutral.
